# NO QUERY using CakePHP Authentication component

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm using CakePHP 2.2.4, and I have started to work with Atuh Componenet.

This is my AppController:

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    public $components = array('Auth', 'Session');

    public function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->authorize = array('Controller');
        $this->Auth->authenticate = array(
            'Form' => array (
                'scope'  => array('User.active' => 1),
                'fields' => array('username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password'),
            )
        );      
    }

    public function isAuthorized($user) {

        debug($user);

        return true;
    }
}
```

This is my User.php model

```
class User extends AppModel {

    public $name = 'User';

    /* Relazioni */
    public $hasOne = 'Profile';

    public $belongsTo = 'Role';

    public $hasMany = array(
        'Lead' => array(
            'className' => 'Lead'
        )
    );  

}
```

and this is my UserController.php

```
<?php

App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class UsersController extends AppController 
{   
    public $name = 'Users';

    public $uses = array();

    public function beforeFilter() 
    {
        parent::beforeFilter();        
    }

    public function login()
    {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) 
        {
            if ($this->Auth->login()) 
            {
                debug('Logged');
            } 
            else 
            {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Login non autorizzato', 'default', array('class' => 'errore'), 'login');
            }
        }   
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }

}
```

I have a strange problem using Auth Component, because at the end of the layout I have sql_dump element, that prints NO QUERY.

However, If i put correct values I do not login

Why does Auth component is not working ?

**EDIT:**

The data of the request is:

```
Array
(
    [User] => Array
        (
            [email] => test@test.it
            [pwd] => abc
        )

)
```

Comment: are you sure the user you are logging in as `active` is set to true?

Comment: @TimJoyce sure, i ma sure..it is set to 1. Btw i think the query is not execute, as i told you in sql_dump element i do not see any output (in other pages i see the dump correctly)

Comment: add `pr($this->request->data);` to your appController before filter at the top then attempt to login and let's see the output there.

Comment: @TimJoyce please take a look at my edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code in AppController is wrong

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->authorize = array('Controller');
    $this->Auth->authenticate = array(
        'Form' => array (
            'scope'  => array('User.active' => 1),
              // password != pwd as you post it
            'fields' => array('username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password'), 
        )
    );      
}
```

Change it to

```
'fields' => array('username' => 'email', 'password' => 'pwd'),
```

or make sure to post `password` instead of `pwd` in your form

Please see https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/Auth/FormAuthenticate.php for documentation on the matter

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to post-fix this answer for anyone arriving here, who is unable to get logged in using Auth for which this example does not DIRECTLY Apply.

An **important** thing to remember is that Auth is expecting the underlying database columns to be "username" and "password". If for whatever reason you defer from this, for example if you want to validate on a users email (very common) and you change the table's column name to reflect this, than you **must** tell Auth about this.

The reason is because the underlying query will fail. Ultimately all that's happening behind the scene is a simply query matching the specified fields. For example (not exact - simply for demonstration purposes -- select *'s are bad):

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'blahblahblah' AND password = 'someInsan31yh4sh3dpassw0rd'
```

If your underlying table is missing a "username" column in loo of an "email" column, than this query will obviously fail. Resulting in the inability to login and usually with no indication that the query failed (it is even omitted from the SQL dump). The following code in your AppController however will solve you issues:

```
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
          'Form' => array(
             'fields' => array('username' => 'columnUsedForValidatingUsername', 'password' => 'columnUserForValidatingPassword')
          )
        )
    )
);
```

Jippi's answer was completely correct in this case. But I feel as though as an answerER on StackOverflow you owe it to anyone finding this to explain WHY the problem is occurring and provide an unspecific answer.

Cheers

Comment: but can you please tell me where this """SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'blahblahblah' AND password = 'someInsan31yh4sh3dpassw0rd'""" exist in file structure